# running series of interactive shell commands in bash/python/perl script

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, shell

Currently, I do the following steps:

a. Grep for pid of a process  and kill it.

```
ps -aux | grep foo.bar  # process of interest
kill -9 pid_of_foo.bar  # kill the process
```

b. start virtualenv

```
cd {required_folder}
sudo virtualenv folder/
cd {folder2}
source bin/activate
```

c. Start the manage.py in shell mode

```
cd {required folder}
sudo python manage.py shell
```

d. In the interactive manage shell, execute the following commands:

```
from core import *
foo.bar.bz.clear.state()
exit
```

e. Execute a script

```
   /baz/maz/foo
```

In bash we can write down a series of commands, however Is it possible to run the interactive shell in django using bash and execute commands? I was wondering if above steps can be scriptified.

Thanks

Comment: Friendly advice: Try "pkill foo.bar" for the first bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

# kill all foo.bar's instances
for pid in $(ps -aux | grep foo.bar | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2;}'); do
    kill $pid
done

# start virtualenv
cd {required_folder}
...

# Start the manage.py in shell mode
cd {required folder}
cat << EOF | sudo python manage.py shell
from core import *
foo.bar.bz.clear.state()
exit
EOF

# Execute a script 
/baz/maz/foo
```

The key point of the script is HEREDOC python snippet. Take a look at the example I've just tried in a console:

```
[alex@galene ~]$ cat <<EOF_MARK | python -
> import sys
> print "Hello, world from python %s" % sys.version
> exit
> EOF_MARK
Hello, world from python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 22 2013, 22:57:56)
[GCC 4.7.2 20121109 (ALT Linux 4.7.2-alt7)]
[alex@galene ~]$ _
```